# Allow only 1 view controller to be in landscape or portrait

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation, landscape-portrait

my app is portrait what i wanna do is allow 1 view controller to be portrait or landscape i tried using this code in AppDelegate but i am getting an error

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow) -> Int {

        let currentViewController: UIViewController? = self.topView


    // Get topmost/visible view controller
    var currentViewController: UIViewController? = self.topViewController
    // Check whether it implements a dummy methods called canRotate
    if currentViewController?.responds(to: #selector(self.canRotate)) {
    // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
    return .allButUpsideDown
    }
    // Only allow portrait (standard behaviour)
    return .portrait
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do that in swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the following approach in my app.

Create a custom UINavigationController with the following code & make sure that your root navigation controller is updated to use this as its class.

```
import UIKit

class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if let _ = presentedViewController as? MyPortraitViewController {
            return .portrait
        }

        return .allButUpsideDown
    }
}
```

You can replace `MyPortraitViewController` with the class name of the view controller you wish to deviate from the global setting.

While I use `.portrait` in this example, you are free to use other options.

One implementation example would be to replace the class of your base navigation controller in your storyboard which is shown below.

[image]

Comment: I tried your code but its never going inside this line if let _ = presentedViewController as? MyPortraitViewController. I just push a view controller.

Comment: @Chandan Can you place a breakpoint at if let _ ... and then run a po presentedViewController to see what you get?

Comment: Thanks @CodeBender. I got the issue.I was pushing a ViewController on NavigationController instead of presentViewController :).

Comment: @tom I updated the answer to include something that may help you

Comment: @CodeBender i tried the code and it is ignoring "return .portrait" and it is using "return .allButUpsideDown" – tom 12 mins ago

Comment: @tom Can you do the same thing I asked of Chandan a few comments above this?

Comment: @CodeBender i did what you asked Chandan to do and i changed from push to present modally but still have the same problem